# Change HTML innerText in element with duplicates

Tags: javascript, html

I want to specifically change the innerText of the "quantity" div from this HTML:

```
<div class="shop" id="shop">
        <div id="1" class="item"> // Div nr. 1
          <div class="details">
            <div class="buttons">
              <div id="1" class="quantity"> // <-- Don't change this one!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="2" class="item"> // Div nr. 2
          <div class="details">
            <div class="buttons">
              <div id="2" class="quantity"> // <-- Change this one!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I tried using `document.querySelector('.quantity').innerText = ""`. But that only changes the first occurring div with the class "quantity", which is within "Div nr. 1".

How do I specifically target the "quantity" class within "Div nr. 2"?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: `.querySelector('#yourDesiredID .quantity')`? (Assuming you remove the duplicate ID on the div that has the `.quantity` class, if you remove the outer ID, you would need to remove the space between the two selectors, e.g. `#yourDesiredID.quantity`)

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.quantity')[1].innerText = "my text"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the html you provided, you can select the second `.item` and then descend to its `.details` like so:
`document.querySelector('.item:nth-child(2) .quantity').innerText="";`

https://jsfiddle.net/6L8gntmh/

It would be wise to make the id`s unique if you have access to the html. Then you would be able to select by their id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelectorAll this allows you to modify HTML elements based on class and id not just one of each.

document.querySelectorAll('.quantity')[1].innerText = "my text"

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific situation, it might be more useful to use a different type of selector:

```
document.querySelector('#id2 .quantity').innerText = ""
```

All ids must be unique and can start with a number, but it's a pain to select, I would recommend starting your id with a letter instead.